# How to check if the user is successful logged out of the Google Sign In Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I am using Google Sign in for authentication. Following the tutorial, I am able to log in. Now I want to log out the user. I got the code for logging out. But how to do I know that the logout is success or fail?

```
    private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // What code should I write here to see if the user has successfully logged out. If not, then I need to display an error message.
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better approach to the question

```
  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(Status status) {

        if (status.isSuccess()) {
          // user logged out successfully
        } else {
          // the logout was not sucessful.
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Google can return 5 types status. Following are the statuses along with the status codes:-

SUCCESS(0), INTERNAL_ERROR(8), INTERRUPTED(14), TIMEOUT(15), CANCELED(16)

So you can check for `status.getStatusCode()` on logout and validate against the above mentioned statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
    status.toString()
```

and log it to find out what details it contains. Then according to it you can use the below methods to check if you have been successfully logged out.

```
   status.getStatusCode();
   status.getStatusMessage();
```

Both methods are self explanatory.